# Element moving when on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been tearing my hair out with this one for a whole day so any help/advice is welcomed!

Basically, my new project uses the Detect mobile browsers script, to check if the user is on a mobile device and if so disable the normal style sheet and enable the mobile style sheet.

I have managed to work out most of the kinks with it but for some reason I am having a problem with a content slider in one of the sections, it has two inline elements in each slide, one floating left (text) and one floating right (image). For some reason when the second slide is clicked the image moves down below the text. Usually this would happen if there is no room but  this is not the case as there is plenty of room for both elements.

This only happens on a mobile device, so you can actually see what I mean by going to http://beta.residencyradio.com and going to the features section, the current version I have working is for tablets, so it is best viewed there.

My thoughts are this must be to do with something in this snippet of code in the mobile stylesheet (below), but I'm not too sure what.

```
#feat {
width: 60em;
margin-top: 3.125em;
display: inline-block;
}

.feat_container {
width: 23.4375em;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 9.0625em;
margin-bottom: 9.0625em;
float: left;
}

.feat_container p {
font-size: 1.125em;
line-height: 1.2em;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.feat_logo {
width: 23.4375em;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin: 0;
}

#feat_nav {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}

#feat_nav a { 
background: url('../images/dot.png') no-repeat;
font-size: 16px;
padding-right: 9px;
text-decoration: none; 
margin-right: 5px; 
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

#feat_nav a.activeSlide { 
background: url('../images/dot_active.png') no-repeat;
}

#PSM .feat_container {
margin-top: 8.375em;
margin-bottom: 8.375em;
}

#PSM, #banger, #hot, #eclectic, #definitive, #guest {
width: 60em;
}

#guest .feat_container {
margin-top: 7.6875em;
margin-bottom: 7.6875em;
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Did you make this with some sort of WSYIWYG editor?  Why such specific `em`s?  Anyway, I don't have a mobile device on me, but I've seen this happen on Android when trying to detect width, and adjusting for it automatically.  It would then fire off another adjustment, causing an endless loop that wouldn't occur on any desktop browser I tested with.  I don't know if that is your problem, but it does look like you do some of your positioning with JS.  Try a raw CSS solution, if possible.

Comment: litterally just got it there now dude, the problem was (for some unknown reason) mobile browsers seem to have a problem rendering the change in with `width` set to a specific value. just changed it to `min-width` and that sorted it out. The reasons for such specific ems is to keep everything exactly as I want it within my grid, to the pixel. Why not use pixels you may wonder, well, in short it has made the crossover from the desktop version to tablet (and eventually mobile) versions an absolute breeze, whilst still keeping an almost identical layout.

Comment: You're kidding - a 1.5mb single page! And all that browser sniffing! Please get someone with good **web** development skills involved in your project.

Comment: Well, its still in a beta testing stage so size at the minute isn't my main concern, getting it to look right is. The single page format is to demonstrate parallax scrolling. Pretty much all of that 1.5mb is in images, which can be cut down by quite a bit when needed. The browser sniffing is to get rid of the parallax elements because they run horribly on touch devices, the sniffing is a quick fix (and bit of experimentation) on my part, for the launch I am going to redirect to a mobile version of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually managed to figure this out after a "light bulb moment". For some reason mobile devices (I have tested on android and ios) seem to have a problem rendering the width of the containing element when the slide is changed, thus forcing the right floated content down.

The fix, simply changing

`#PSM, #banger, #hot, #eclectic, #definitive, #guest {
width: 60em;
}`

to

`#PSM, #banger, #hot, #eclectic, #definitive, #guest {
max-width: 60em;
}`

And that sorts it out, hope it helps someone!